# How do I prevent line wrapping in HSPICE output tables?

Tags: spice

For example, I have the following `.measure` lines in my HSPICE netlist:

```
.measure a1 <measure_spec>
.measure a2 <measure_spec>
.measure a3 <measure_spec>
.measure a4 <measure_spec>
```

It annoys me that HSPICE outputs the table (with the `.mt0` extension) line-wrapped:

```
a1    a2    a3    a4
  temper    alter#
1.23  4.56  3.21  4.32
  25.00     1
```

How do I prevent it from wrapping the lines?

Comment: Please try this: `.option measform=1`

Comment: I tend to write scripts to clean up post processing using regex and various *nix tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HSPICE Quick Reference Guide](http://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/es154/hspice_quick_ref.pdf) posted at Harvard, there is a .WIDTHOUT card that you can use to set the number of columns in the output before linewrapping occurs:

```
.WIDTHOUT=132
```

Unfortunately it also says that the only choices are 80 or 132 columns, so if you're wrapping at 132 columns you might just have to reduce the number of nodes  output or use a binary format.

Remember that SPICE was developed in the days of punchcard i/o, and the .PRINT output is meant to actually be printed up on a lineprinter and read by eye.

Answer (score 0):

In recent hspice versions there is an option called measform. Set this option to 3 and it will output the measurement in CSV format in one line per sweep step.

e.g.

> .option measform=3